# Template routing stopped working after server migration

Tags: templates, migration, routing

We migrated a site we've been working on to a new server with the same host, the server spec is technically greater but from a software perspective it's running the same flavour of Apache, PHP and MySQL... however since migration template routing has stopped working.

The routes are still there in the ExpressionEngine Control Panel but they all appear to just resolve to the template you would expect if routing was not running.

Just putting this out there in case anyone else has run into it...? :/

We're running 2.8.1 on Apache 2.4.10 with PHP 5.4.30.

Comment: Ok, I think my problem is that for some reason URL Segment Support isn't enabled on the new server! I re-ran the server wizard and that highlighted the problem!  Now I just have to work out how to enable it!

Comment: Ok so I set up a test page on the server I migrated from and the one I migrated to which checks whether PATH_INFO is set and it is on both... which confuses me even more. It appears to be 'template routing' specifically which is not working, URL rewriting etc works just fine. :/